# MatPlotlib from Spyder vs IPython

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, spyder

I'm working through a tutorial on MatPlotlib and I initially started using Spyder's IPython console.  The very simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(1, 5)
plt.plot(x, [xi*1.5 for xi in x])
plt.plot(x, [xi*3.0 for xi in x])
plt.plot(x, [xi/3.0 for xi in x])
plt.show()
```

in Ipython only produces a plot once plt.show() is executed, and that plot has 3 lines on it - as expected.  But in Spyder's IPython console, I get a plot every time plt.plot() is executed, and plt.show() doesn't seem to have any effect at all.  Each individual plot only has one line plotted on it rather than the 3 lines I see at the end of the code with IPython.

Is there a way to make Spyder behave like IPython?

Comment: If I try it with IPython Qt console it works as expected

Comment: Is spyder trying to use the 'inline' or similar backend?  Also try using the OO api instead of the state machine (`pyplot`) api.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I've tried both of those and I still get the same results.  What I've found, though, is that if I cut and paste the full block of code above, it behaves as expected with only one plot having 3 lines.  If I type the lines in one at a time, I get a plot after each plt.plot line.  If I press Ctrl+Enter after each line, it works as expected, but I actually don't need the plt.show() line.  In an IPython console (outside of Spyder) I can enter each line as shown followed by Enter and get the expected result, and I have to use plt.show in order to see the figure at the end.

Comment: Also, regardless of whether I set the graphics backend to inline, automatic, QT, TKinter, I get the same result.